# ERROR in ./node_modules/file-base64/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'

Tags: vue.js, npm, base64, fs

I'm using vue js and laravel mix.
I dl the file-base64 npm package.

And when i compile, i get this error =>

ERROR in ./node_modules/file-base64/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'

in the file-base-64 it import `var fs = require('fs');`

But i have access the fs.d.ts file. It feels the when it compile, it don't have a direct access.

Do someone got the same issue?

Comment: your code is running in browser. fs module is available in node only.

Comment: @VaibhavVishal I don't get how the 2 are different. So how can it work in the browser. Do i need to install a package ?

Comment: it can't work, js code running in browser can't access filesystem. Otherwise website you visit will start reading/writing the files saved on your computer

Comment: @VaibhavVishal Thanks a lot. It makes sense now that you mention it